# Using navigation safe args at the module level

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I get the following error whenever I am trying to sync the project with the gradle files after I add the navigatoin safe args dependencies to my module level build.gradle file.

```
Plugin [id: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'] was not found in any of the following sources
```

However it works when I add it to the project level build.gradle file. Is it possible to add the dependency only to the module level or will I have to add it to my project level build.gradle?

The buildscript block. I have placed it at the beginning of the module level gradle file.

```
buildscript { 
   dependencies {
    classpath deps.navigation.safeargs
   } 
}
```